# Should a REST API always document its response content?

Tags: rest, api-design

I am using a REST API that is being developed at my workplace. The documentation clearly states the HTTP request type (POST), the URL endpoint, and the "payload" in curly brackets, i.e., various parameters and expected values. At the bottom of each endpoint section, it details response possibilities as response codes - 200 for success, 400 for an error, and so on. It doesn't say anything about what the API call will return if successful, i.e., a nested list of different data attributes and so on, so you can know what to expect and how to swiftly extract the data you are seeking; and these methods must certainly return data, by their nature.

Is it common to leave out the structure of the response data in a REST API documentation or is this poor practice?

Comment: It definitely helps to have it but my experience with building APIs is that a lot of the time, the client developers don't look at it and just assume what comes back is representative of what they will always see.  You might want to ask about what tooling they are using to generate this.  They may not be taking full advantage of it.

Comment: surely REST requires no documentation

Comment: I'm wondering whether @Ewan's comment and the answer by Robert Bräutigam below are somehow sarcastic and I'm just not getting the joke, or meant seriously.

Comment: slightly sarcastic. by the book REST needs no documentation, its kind of the point. No-one does REST by the book, but everyone says REST is amazing and everything should be RESTful.

Comment: also json, which again isnt really part of REST but is universally used, dosent have a nice schema language which you could use to define the return types, unlike XML which everyone hates. So yeah, best practice is "use WCF"

Comment: @Ewan Are you not aware of JSON Schema, or are you just saying it isn't "nice"?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I think both are overstating or mis-stating Roy Fielding's ideas: he absolutely did *not* say that a RESTful API requires no prior knowledge on the part of the client. What he *did* argue for was structuring that prior knowledge in a particular, abstracted, way that maximised the flexibility of the API.

Comment: i am aware of json schema, I wonder if anyone actually uses it? the point is people moved away from SOAP which has all this stuff towards a less rigorous you get what you get approach. To now turn around and say, you should have machine readable documentation for your REST APIs? well you might as well have suck with xml and SOAP etc

Comment: @Ewan Yes, it is in use: https://swagger.io/specification/ and no it's not anywhere near as bad as XSD.

Comment: @Ewan I sympathise somewhat: I think XML is more suitable for some purposes than JSON, and there is an element of fashion that leads to re-inventing the wheel with things like JSON Schema. (Which incidentally makes the same mistake as XSD of trying to be homoiconic, rather than domain-specific, like RelaxNG.) However, SOAP has a lot of design flaws, and in practice configuring a SOAP client to work with a particular service takes as long as it would to implement a simple XML serialize/deserialize routine based on decent documentation. The needs of APIs vary too much to standardise everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably both common and poor practice :-) (I don't have enough experience with what others do to leave out the "probably")

Have a look at OpenAPI (https://www.openapis.org/) and Swagger (https://swagger.io/). They have a rich model for expressing API specs and documentation, and there exists tooling for many languages. Since the format is well-documented, it is possible to create well-readable documents from OpenAPI JSON. The spec places emphasis on providing data structure documentation as well as API endpoint docs.

OpenAPI does not enforce that the API implementation actually conforms to the specification, but in cases where API provider and consumer disagree, it is a good reference for deciding which one should adapt.

Comment: Based on the description in the question, it sounds like they are using something like swagger or redoc but are not generating/documenting the response schema.  When I first started using FastAPI, for example, I wasn't specifying the pydantic models that it uses to generate those schemas so I would get something like what is described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no it should not. What resource / page a server returns to you after processing your request is up to the server and may change without notice depending on some state, context, parameters or software updates, etc.

As long as the server can send *media types* that the client understands, the client does not need to know the type / structure of resource that will be returned in advance.

It is also completely unnecessary to document return codes (those are part of the HTTP specification and their meaning is known already) or URIs / parameters / methods (hypermedia will specify those).

If you use none of that and hardcode everything into the client, then sure, document the return structure.

Comment: The question was about an API, not a web server where you'd expect a human to decipher the response as rendered by their browser. The interpretation of API responses **is** typically hardcoded into the client.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner The question was specifically about REST APIs, which _were_ originally designed to work just like websites. I know, it is not used that way today, you're right. I sometimes feel though the decision to ignore what its original purpose was is not made deliberately, so it has some value to mention how it supposed to work.

Comment: Fielding's thesis talks about the REST architectural style, not about APIs. When APIs are involved, their input and output data formats need to be documented. This applies to all kinds of APIs, whether they are implemented using direct function calls, remote procedure calls, or HTTP interactions in the REST architectural style. Without a specification of valid input/output data you have REST, but not an API.

Comment: REST APIs are documented through *Media-Types*. **Not** through hardcoding input/output/endpoint combinations. You *can not assume* that "/person/123" will give you a person-json. Maybe it'll give you a login screen first, or a disambiguation screen, etc. I know, it's not done this way today, but I think Fielding is pretty clear about how REST applies to specifically APIs: https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: @RobertBräutigam, how does (the developer of) a client know which media types they need to implement?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau That _is_ the documentation. The set of media-types you'll need. In fact it is the only thing the documentation of a REST API should contain. At no point should any URIs be mentioned, either for media-types to be used as request content, nor where a media-type will be returned as response content.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Frankly, I don't think this answer is helpful to the OP.  It's impractical to think that people are going to register new MIME types or whatever for each new document they need to return or that the client developers are going build code to discover the API every single time they call it.  I think it's time to accept that the term REST API has gotten away from Fielding.  Yes, this is not what he meant but it's what most people mean when they talk about REST.  I feel bad that his term got hijacked but it's over.  He doesn't even blog about it anymore, to my knowledge.

Comment: I think you could keep most of this answer, but turn it into a "yes": you *should* document what the responses will look like, *but you should do so by defining custom content types*, rather than responses to individual actions. In the same way, you can say that you *should* document the available actions, *but you should do so by defining custom link types*, not individual URLs.

Comment: @JimmyJames You're right I think and I sort-of (?) accept that REST means almost the opposite of what it was supposed to mean. I still think the original way (or a much more closer interpretation) is much more practical and maintainable though (having designed such APIs myself). It just _seems_ impractical because nobody seems to have a good example and most do not even know there are other ways to do it. I understand everyone in this thread, I just would like to leave the "other" (original?) way here for reference and hope that it provides value for people looking for that explicitly.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I can accept that.  Part of my frustration is that I've dealt with a lot of wasted time (not just here) arguing about what is and isn't RESTful and most of the time, none of the arguments are correct according to Fielding.  It's like "that's not RESTful" became an ad hominem attack somehow.  I do like Fielding's thesis, though.  It's still worth reading any understanding even if it's not what people mean by 'REST'.

Comment: Having said that, I was thinking about this and one of the big challenges of using MIME types for custom internal datatypes is that I don't know of any standard for documenting them other than registering them globally.  Are there any frameworks or approaches built upon the idea of internal MIME types?  Another challenge is that writing code to deal with an API that can change from under you at any moment is no small feat.  If you know of tools techniques that are make this practical, I'd love to know what they are.

Comment: i thoguth the client could request a media type

Comment: @JimmyJames I've used the vendor and unregistered trees for company / internal stuff. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Vendor_tree) Don't need to register everything. The beauty of Mime-types is that you concentrate on what it means, not technical details, therefore simple text is sufficient. As to dealing with changes, discovery and content-negotiation. It is not that difficult once you commit. Here is my small experimental library for how it could be done: https://github.com/vanillasource/gerec/wiki/Navigation

Comment: @RobertBräutigam That's awesome.  I wasn't even aware of the vendor and unregistered tree.  I think this is where the 'war for the minds' has been lacking from the 'true REST' side of things.  I've read so much pontificating on what people are doing wrong but practical advice on how to do it right is severely lacking.  I will definitely check your library out and thanks.  If I could upvote again, I would.

Comment: So one more thought on this.  Is there anything wrong with having a schema for a mimetype?  I mean, no one would expect to be able to retrieve an MP4 and process it without some definition of what its structure is.  That relationship though is implicit.  You say it's MP4 and you have some documentation somewhere that tells you what that means and you have some sort of lib to deal with it.  But I think it's actually cooler to have a link to a machine readable spec that your client can use to parse the format.  That could even help address versioning challenges.

Comment: @JimmyJames In a comment under the blog post Robert Bräutigam linked to earlier, Roy Fielding said: "Of course the client has prior knowledge. Every protocol, every media type definition, every URI scheme, and every link relationship type constitutes prior knowledge that the client must know (or learn) in order to make use of that knowledge. REST doesn’t eliminate the need for a clue." That's why I don't think this answer is helpful even under its own terms: the answer is not "don't document your responses", it's "document your responses as media type definitions".

Comment: @RobertBräutigam "The beauty of Mime-types is that you concentrate on what it means, not technical details, therefore simple text is sufficient." This is, frankly, nonsense: at some point, the client has to know how to parse the actual representation that is returned. The [example on this page](https://github.com/vanillasource/gerec/wiki/Jackson-JSON) is only possible with technical knowledge of the format of the "application/vnd.company.person-v1+json" media type. The API also cannot change that definition, or stop supporting that media type, without breaking all clients using it.

Comment: @IMSoP You're right on both points. My response was specifically in the context of the OP. It was specifically about documenting the endpoint itself, whether you should specify what the API call returns specifically. That you don't do. Regarding schemas. You have to describe the "schema" of course. I would use text/examples for that too, but you can use machine-readable formats if you want. Again, what I mean is that most stuff that is usually defined in OpenAPI/Swagger, you don't have to even mention. Basically you only need the textual "documentation" part.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I'm still not sure I agree: it's no use telling your generic REST client to do something when it receives an "application/vnd.company.person-v1+json" resource, when that part of the API actually only returns "application/vnd.company.employee-v1+json" resources. The information about what is supported would be tied to media types and link types rather than URLs, but it all still needs to be there, so that integrators don't have to program by trial and error. I'd be interested to know your thoughts on my answer, where I've tried to explain my understanding of all this.

Comment: @IMSoP The point is, looking at a link you can not tell what representations are available on the other end. It might be, that the server can only return an "employee" for a certain request, but you are not supposed to just assume that. And it is not even necessary actually, if you just design the client a bit differently. I don't really get the different between just media types and "link types" / "relation types" in your answer.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam [The example you shared earlier](https://github.com/vanillasource/gerec/wiki/Navigation) makes exactly that assumption: it assumes that it will get back something matching `Person.MEDIA_TYPE`; how can anyone write code with that assumption, except based on documentation? By "link types"/"relationship types", I mean the "rel" attribute of the HTML "link" element, or its equivalent in other representations. The thing that lets you distinguish between e.g. "author", "editor", and "subject of biography", which might all be represented with a "person" media type.

Comment: @IMSoP In the example I do not assume any ordering. If the search immediately returns a "person" (a'la "I'm feeling lucky") that navigation still works. If there is no search page at all, because the system has only 10 entries and those are immediately displayed, it still works. The `navigate()` calls are all independent a may never be called at all or called multiple times or in any ordering, whatever. The server decides on the workflow, not the client. Was that the missing information?

Comment: @RobertBräutigam If the API doesn't display a search page, the example breaks, returning all retired people, rather than all retired people named "jack". If the API returns result items of a type other than Person, it breaks, because it will treat it as "no results". If the search page returns a "current user" link, and you happen to be retired, it will break, because it will return that user. All of those assumptions are based on "prior knowledge" of the API, which means they must have been documented somewhere for the person to think that code was correct.

Comment: @IMSoP Hehe :) You're right on the first one, I got carried away there. I think we're running in circles though. I never said there are no prior assumptions. The client must know all relevant media-types in advance, obviously. It does _not_ need to know the endpoints, their ordering, specific responses returned, etc. in advance though. Again, this was the OP's question.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam To put my point more succinctly: I think you are over-emphasising the distinction between "specific responses returned" and "media types". Just because it's not associated to a specific URL, documenting a media type for a set of search results is still documenting a specific response, which the client will need to make assumptions about.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I think your "ordering can be ignored" concept is fundamentally broken, though, as the search example shows. To take another example, consider a task to find *the children of* everyone named "Jack". The children will be represented by the same Person media type, and might have their own children, so the client code *has to* distinguish between "Person returned from initial search" and "Person returned from child link". In procedural code, that is trivial; in your "order agnostic navigation", it requires extra state logic, which will break in the same way if the API changes.

Comment: @IMSoP You're making really good points. :) Maintaining your own state and not mixing it with the server's workflow is a good thing, that makes the client generally simpler though. For example when I need to buy 2 things on amazon, I'll have to keep the state of my progress in my head. That's ok. I don't assume though what pages I get on some random click. That two are not the same. Also you're right, the server is not free to change the "order" (i.e. worklfow) in every way, it has to make sense for the use-case at hand. I think that is a reasonable constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There are two, somewhat orthogonal questions, here:

1. Should an API provide documentation on its outputs as well its inputs?
2. How should that documentation be provided *in the context of a RESTful design*?

The answer to question 1 is a resounding "yes": any client needs to have knowledge somewhere of what information it can retrieve from an API, or the API has no practical use. If I want to display some products results from your API, I absolutely need to know whether they have a description, an image URL, etc, and how to extract those from a particular representation.

The answer to question 2 is much more subtle. In a true REST design, there are no defined URLs, and so there can be no defined responses from sending requests to those URLs. Instead, there are defined **content types**, and defined **relationship types**.

Content types are fairly straight-forward to think about: think about XML or JSON schemas for entities like "Product" or "SearchResultList", but then add the *semantics* (meaning) as well as the *syntax* (structure and format). All the requests and responses used by the API should use documented content types.

Relationship types are less easily understood, and the part that few "RESTish" APIs actually implement. I will also probably explain it really badly, so take everything in this paragraph with a grain of salt, and read up on "HATEOAS" if you're interested. The idea is that as part of a content type like "SearchResultList" would be elements which are simply links to other API end-points, each labelled with an identifier. Those identifiers would then be documented *separately* from that particular type, e.g. "wherever you see a 'product-item' link, the URL is somewhere you can fetch a 'Product' entity".

So in a true RESTful API, there should never be a document saying "URL /products/42 will return JSON in this format", because there should be no document specifying the URL /products/42 at all. But **you definitely need to document your data representations somewhere**.

Answer (score -1):

If I were tasked with writing code which intended to use the API, then ***yes*** I would need a definitive description of what exactly to expect.  Don't leave me guessing.  Don't waste my time.